# How to split a dataframe into chunks when a particular column value occurs (R)?

Tags: r

I am trying to split a dataframe into chunks, based on a particular value in a column (rather than a grouping value), so every time the column matches this value, it should chunk the dataframe. For example, with dataframe x:

```
f1 f2
 3  0
 4  1
 5  2
 6  0
 7  1
 8  2
 9  3
```

How would I split x to be a list of, where the split occurs anytime "f2"==0:

```
[1]
f1 f2
 3  0
 4  1
 5  2
[2]
f1 f2
 6  0
 7  1
 8  2
 9  3
```

I have tried

```
     split(x, x$f2 == 0)
```

which just creates a list of two elements, one where x x$f2 == 0 is FALSE and one where x$f2 == 0 is TRUE.

I have also tried to use apply() as in

```
     mm <- apply(x, function(x)  split(x$f2 == 0))
```

but I get the error "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default"

Code to make a simple dataframe as above:

```
     f1 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
     f2 <- c(0,1,2,0,1,2,3)
     x <- data.frame(f1,f2)
```

Comment: `split(x, cumsum(x$f2 == 0))`

Answer (score 4):

Using base R's `split` with for example `cumsum` like this would be a way:

```
split(x, cumsum(x$f2 == 0))
```

Output

```
# $`1`
#   f1 f2
# 1  3  0
# 2  4  1
# 3  5  2
# 
# $`2`
#   f1 f2
# 4  6  0
# 5  7  1
# 6  8  2
# 7  9  3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can do (basically the same thing as the idea by @jogo):

```
df %>%
 group_split(cumsum(f2 == 0), keep = FALSE)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     f1    f2
  <int> <int>
1     3     0
2     4     1
3     5     2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     f1    f2
  <int> <int>
1     6     0
2     7     1
3     8     2
4     9     3
```